# Python-Selenium-Chromedriver gives ConnectionResetError on AWS-EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver, ubuntu-16.04

I have an application using Selenium/Chromedriver, running chrome headlessly. On my local machine, it works perfectly. When trying to run on an AWS-EC2 instance of Ubuntu 16.04, I get an error each time;

```
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

The outbound rules for the security group allows all traffic on all ports.

The reset by peer error suggests that I'm getting locked out by the server, but I can't explain why I can still run locally? Any insight as to the source of the error?

Setup:

- Python 3.6
- Chromedriver 2.34
- Selenium 3.8.1

Note: Using Robobrowser from the same server completes without issue.

SteveJ

Comment: did you find a fix for this?

Comment: @AlexW I found a workaround. I switched over to the gecko driver and all seems to be working. I haven't looked back since.

Answer (score 0):

I have had mild success w/ the follow code. Please note, it is still very finicky... its seems that, after one driver session, the server stops the connection (104 error we see).

First, make sure to download the appropriate chromedriver. Follow this gist: https://gist.github.com/ziadoz/3e8ab7e944d02fe872c3454d17af31a5

Next, run /usr/local/bin/chromedriver to start chomedriver. you should see:

Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565383

Next, open a new Putty console and set up your WebDriver. My preferred set up is:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver

chrome_options = Options()
chromes_options.set_headless()

driver=WebDriver('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
## Note the above 'executable path' of the chromedriver is based on the above gist
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

Hopefully this is useful.

Additional troubleshooting may include:

++ ensure you have assigned a public key to your google-chrome (as seen here: https://krbnite.github.io/Driving-Headless-Chrome-with-Selenium-on-AWS-EC2/#comment-3951560468)

++ pass the following flags to your chrome options:
  '--no-sandbox' & '--disable-dev-shm-usage'

++ make sure to "sudo killall -9 chrome" after you have run your script to ensure your chromedriver instance is gone!

Comment: Additional troubleshooting may include:

++ ensure you have assigned a public key to your google-chrome (as seen here: https://krbnite.github.io/Driving-Headless-Chrome-with-Selenium-on-AWS-EC2/#comment-3951560468)

++ pass the following flags to your chrome options:
  '--no-sandbox' & '--disable-dev-shm-usage'